# django template not looping correctly

Tags: python, json, django

I have the following:

```
In [3]: Model.objects.get(id=123).field
Out[3]: 
{u'1': None,
 u'2': u'label 1',
 u'3': u'label 2',
 u'4': u'label 3',
 u'5': None,
 u'6': u'label 4',
 u'7': None,
 u'8': u'label 5',
}
```

and I have a view with the following template load:

```
mapping = Model.objects.get(id=123).field
return render(request, 'final_application.html', {'predictions':mapping,...})
```

but when I try and iterate over this in my template, it only includes the JSON where the value is None. Here is the code I tried

```
function run(){
    {% for tag_id, suggestion in predictions.items %}
        alert(tag_id); // just to display how it does not go through the whole JSON for some reason
        //do the stuff I want to
    {% endfor %}
}
```

This function is run through the following HTML

```
<button id="accept" onclick="run();">accept</button>
```

this alerts 1, then 5, then 7, which are the only tags with the value as None. Why does this happen instead of it iterating through the entire JSON? Is there something I am missing?

## extra note

since people want to know what else is run in the for loop, I tested the code with everything other than the `alert` commented out, and it behaves the same way. This displays that what is in the loop is irrelevant. Note that I also am not allowed to disclose the information inside the loop.

Comment: So you are making an ajax call for this from your template ?

Comment: What does the rendered HTML source look like?

Comment: @TanveerAlam There is no ajax call. If you look, I declare the JSON in a variable that I pass to the template

Comment: @DanielHepper I cannot post the HTML source code for confidential reasons. What exactly in that would you need to look at?

Comment: Then how come you are getting alert inside your body? can you share more of your template code.

Comment: @Ryan Saxe The part produced by the for-loop is the most relevant. Is there an alert() for every entry in the `mapping`?

Comment: @TanveerAlam That is in the javascript portion of the template. It is in a `<script>` tag. And the actual template code is very extensive and I can only share snippits. if I am told what I need to show, I can show it.

Comment: Is this your _exact_ (obfuscated) code? There is no logic that really filters the non-None fields out. In your view, can you make sure the json dict is the same as what you get in the shell

Comment: @DanielHepper the for loop is inside a function that is called on a button click. There is no HTML that is created from it on document load. Could that be the problem?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the *shortest code necessary to reproduce it* in the question itself

Comment: @karthikr this is the exact portion of the code. I will provide a bit more extensive description and when this for loop will run in one minute

Comment: @C.B. I do explicitly state what the specific problem is. The problem is that I am passing JSON with many values, some of which are `None`, but when I loop through it in my template, it only loops through the fields that have None values for some reason I cannot explain.

Comment: @RyanSaxe right my point is that without more code at this point it doesn't seem reproduceable, and due to the confidential nature of your code you probably won't be able to provide it.

Comment: @C.B. That is a valid statement. I was hoping that somebody had come across this problem before. There may be something that is interfering somewhere, either in the view or template as I know the model is fine. And there is way too much code to display so I am unable to rewrite it in a fashion that maintains the confidentiality of the code. Thanks anyways

Comment: I'd like to know what `field` is, and where is the logic that translates that into a Python dict.

Comment: @DanielRoseman it is a [JSONField](https://github.com/derek-schaefer/django-json-field)

Comment: it look like the problem must be in here: `//do the stuff I want to` or else the dict that you're getting in your template context isn't actually the one in your example code at the top of the question

Comment: @Anentropic I did state that if I comment out everything inside the `//do the stuff I want to`, it behaves the exact same way. For some reason, the dict must be different, but when I check the dict in the view before I pass it to the template, it is correct, so I don't understand how this is possible.

Comment: do you do anything else with `{{ predictions }}` in the template? what if you just output it in the HTML - does it have all the keys and values?

Comment: does your real code have `alert({{ tag_id }})`, instead of `alert(tag_id)`